# AVPlayer pauses for no obvious reason

Tags: ios, avplayer

While playing a video, I'm seeing rate change notifications from `AVPlayer` that don't seem to be connected to app activity.

When my app receives a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification, I tell the `AVPlayer` to `pause`.  The logic is that it should come back to the foreground at the same place the user left.  If I do not call `pause` when going to the background, the problem doesn't appear.

The sequence of events sent to the player is `pause`, `seekToTime:`, `play`.  Generally, this works fine but, after the app has been sent to the background and then returned to the foreground, each `play` invocation results in two rate changes from the `AVPlayer`.  The first is to 1 and the second, immediately following, is to 0.  This pattern continues for each call to  `-[AVPlayer play]` as long as that player instance is in use.

I'm able to put a breakpoint on `-[AVPlayer pause]` and I do not see it being hit when the rate changes to 0.  If I comment out the `seekToTime:` call, the problem goes away.  If I use `seekToTime:completionHandler:`, I also get the same problem although my block's `finished` parameter is `YES`.

Apart from "how do I fix this", I'm interested in any details about how to detect the reason for rate changes in `AVPlayer` that aren't connected to `play`/`pause`.  (Putting a breakpoint on `-[AVPlayer setRate:]` never seems to trigger.)

(*One workaround that almost works is to save the player position when entering the background, let it play, and fix the position when returning to the foreground.  This also requires some manipulation of audio levels, which is probably doable, but another problem is that not all background notifications indicate that the view has been obscured (e.g. double-tap home button).  This leads to cases where my workaround shows a distracting moving image when the app is interrupted but still visible.*)

Suggestions?

---

(*A last bit of extra information: In all the cases I've tried, I eventually get to a state where the AVPlayer is changing the rate from 1 to 0 moments after I invoke 'play' if I've returned from the background and then performed a seek.  There are things I can do to make it less frequent but none that eliminate it except getting rid of the AVPlayer and creating a new instance.  This results is very long delays but is better than a complete malfunction...I guess.*

*I have some evidence that the seek distance affects the result, which suggests that the error might be in the underlying buffering mechanism.  Without knowing what causes the rate change (other than play/pause) I don't see a way to investigate further.*)

Comment: Show some Code to fix your Problem.

Comment: @iProgrammed - I don't think it'll help; the code is implicitly: `[player pause]; [player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero]; [player play];`.  The problem isn't so much in the code as it is in the fact that the player's rate is set to zero at times when `pause` is not being called.

Comment: @vaughan -- This is still essentially an unsolved problem with no answers here, the Apple forums, or by trial and error.  The best I've been able to do is keep track of whether I expect a rate=0 change and, if I get an unexpected one, schedule a "play" with a quarter-second delay.  If I try that a few times in a row with no good result, I reset the AVPlayer.  Annoying hack, but it **mostly** gets me tolerable playback performance.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting an `AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification`.

Try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  addObserverForName:AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification
  object:cell.avPlayerItem
  queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    DDLogVerbose(@"%@", @"AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification");
  }];
```

However, Apple docs say `Playback will continue once a sufficient amount of media has subsequently been delivered.` (https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009532-CH1-SW83)

This is not happening for me or you.

I am still tracking the reason down.

---

**EDIT:**

This was the problem for me. When `AVPlayerItem.likelyToKeepUp` was YES then it wouldn't happen.

Not sure why it wasn't resuming.

---

**EDIT:**

From the Apple docs there is a situation where playback will not resume:

> This property communicates a prediction of playability. Factors
>   considered in this prediction include I/O throughput and media decode
>   performance. It is possible for playbackLikelyToKeepUp to indicate NO
>   while the property playbackBufferFull indicates YES. In this event the
>   playback buffer has reached capacity but there isn't the statistical
>   data to support a prediction that playback is likely to keep up in the
>   future.
>
> **It is up to you to decide whether to continue media playback.**

Comment: That's possible but I'd need some #ifdef's since I have the added wrinkle of trying to support 5.1.1.  :)

Comment: Curious about your architecture....  Local playback or network streaming?  (I have a local file served via byte ranges from a built-in localhost proxy.)

Comment: I am streaming from an S3 bucket.